# Permission Denied when creating new file Android

Tags: android, permissions, audio-recording

I am working on audio recorder app for android, and I have this problem.
I have two test devices, 1 is running on 4.3 other is running on 4.0. So far I was using device running on 4.3 for testing and I got no errors. But today I tested on 4.0 device and I got this error:

```
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/MyPadRecords/My Record 5.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:419)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:629)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at soundmaniacs.com.MainClass$2.onClick(MainClass.java:138)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-18 11:36:17.910: W/System.err(3320):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-18 11:36:17.920: W/System.err(3320):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 11:36:17.920: W/System.err(3320): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-18 11:36:17.920: W/System.err(3320):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-18 11:36:17.920: W/System.err(3320):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
07-18 11:36:17.920: W/System.err(3320):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:403)
07-18 11:36:17.920: W/System.err(3320):     ... 16 more
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/MediaRecorder(3320): start called in an invalid state: 4
07-18 11:36:17.920: D/AndroidRuntime(3320): Shutting down VM
07-18 11:36:17.920: W/dalvikvm(3320): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320): java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320):     at soundmaniacs.com.MainClass$2.onClick(MainClass.java:144)
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-18 11:36:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3320):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have permissions to record:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

And here is my code:

```
  File FolderCreator = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/MyPadRecords");
        File FileCreator;
```

On Create:

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        }

        if (!FolderCreator.exists()) {
            if (FolderCreator.mkdir()) {
            }

        }
```

And then simple recording code:

```
@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (recording == false) {

                        SharedPreferences FileExtensionPreference = PreferenceManager
                                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                        int savedvalue = FileExtensionPreference.getInt(
                                "FileExtensionValue", num);
                        num = savedvalue;
                        num++;
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager
                                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                                        getApplicationContext()).edit();
                        editor.putInt("FileExtensionValue", num);
                        editor.commit();
                        FileCreator = new File(FolderCreator, "My Record " + num
                                + ".mp3");

                        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                        recorder.setMaxDuration(700000);
                        recorder.setMaxFileSize(40000000);
                        recorder.setOutputFile(FileCreator.getAbsolutePath());

                        try {
                            recorder.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        recorder.start();
                        recording = true;
                        Toast.makeText(MainClass.this, "Recording started",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        record.setImageResource(R.drawable.selector_stoprecord);
                    } else {
                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder.reset();
                        recorder.release();
                        record.setImageResource(R.drawable.selector_record);
                        recording = false;
                        Toast.makeText(
                                MainClass.this,
                                "Recording stopped, file is being saved to"
                                        + FileCreator, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Line 144 is `recorder.start();`
Why am I getting this error? Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: can You show us please Your manifest file? I know You set the right permissions, but are You sure You set them into the right place?

Comment: and another thought, are You trying to record on that device while it is connected via USB? Some devices have problems with this...

Comment: That was it -.-. I disconnected device and it worked. Can you write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some devices have problems with connecting to the pc via usb and writing to external storage at the same time. It´s bad for debugging, but this issue relies on the manufacturer. Just disable the device from usb and it will work.